# I want to implement a search progress in Google maps like in the Image below

Tags: android, google-maps

[image]
I need a transparent circle to show a search progress on Google map which increases its size per second, and also put some markers on it during search.

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: I searched about how to show circle on the Google map and also try to use surface view to implement this but I did't get success, and also try to solve my problem with the help of custom progress bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Finally I got the solution. I just simply use an image and set it on the map screen and add animation on it and it works perfect.
Here is the code of my map class.
progressBar = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.mapprogressbar);

```
    RotateAnimation rotateAnimation1 = new RotateAnimation(0, 360,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    rotateAnimation1.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    rotateAnimation1.setDuration(1000);
    rotateAnimation1.setRepeatCount(1000);
    progressBar.startAnimation(rotateAnimation1);
```

this fulfil my need**

Answer (score 1):

Create an image that looks like this, with a transparent background, put it on top of the map, and rotate it a bit to the right every millisecond or so.

If you provide more details what you would need to know, maybe I'm able to answer it.

Comment: But I also want to increase the size of the circle on every sec and some markers on which I can click during the search to proceed further.

Comment: Maybe you should ask your questions one at a time and describe it in more detail. I don't really get what you want to do. Images you can manipulate from the code, i.e. change size, rotation, etc.

Answer (score 0):

use a SweepGradient http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SweepGradient.html, set it to a Canvas using setShader and finally draw an arc